# how to bind THIS to an external function in php

Tags: javascript, php

I spent a good amount time learning javascript.Now i've come to php world and felt kind of lost at first when i started learning OOP in php.In javascript i can bind/apply/call external functions to do some specific job.How can i manage this behavior in php?Here i have  simple javascript code which uses apply method .How can i do the same thing using php.I know declaration of class is different.And variable visibility is also there.I just want to know is there any way to imitate bind/apply/call functionality in php??

js code is below::

```
function Person(name,haircolor){
   this.name=name;
   this.haircolor=haircolor;

}

function display(){

  console.log(this.name+' has '+this.haircolor+' hair.');
}

var person1=new Person('zami','black');

display.apply(person1);
```

Comment: JS implementation is something extraordinary that only must live there and must not be taken to other languages. Coding idiomatically means that you code using idioms from the language you use. PS: fortunately it's impossible to do in php

Comment: what is so fortunate about this if it is impossible??

Comment: It is fortunate because it encourages weird techniques (which makes already bad code even worse). In the given example your `display()` function should just accept a `person` argument then you run it as `display(person1);` Perfectly clear and readable.

Comment: Or you can have `display()` inside the `Person` class and you can call `$person1->display();`. Perfectly clear and readable.

Comment: @invisal ... or not. It's not a good idea for the domain object to know how to render itself. If you have it outside - you can have millions of implementations each of which "displays" it in a different way.

Comment: @zerkms, I don't get your point. `display()` in this case only display name and haircolor. If you have a `Car`, obviously, there will be no haircolor and you would want to display differently and it is very clear to have `$car->display()` and `$person->display()` then, `display($car); display($person)`.

Comment: it can display haircolor or anyting.It's about can i bind THIS explicitly to this function in php..

Comment: @invisal my point is that the domain object must not be the one responsible for its rendering. One day you want to introduce i18n to `display` output. Congratulations, now your domain object know about languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call-time binding is a peculiarity very specific to Javascript (not exclusively, but largely). Most other languages bind the object context before that, irreversibly. The best you could do in PHP is shown in [the manual for the `Closure` class](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php), the internal implementation for anonymous functions:

```
class A {
    function __construct($val) {
        $this->val = $val;
    }
    function getClosure() {
        //returns closure bound to this object and scope
        return function() { return $this->val; };
    }
}

$ob1 = new A(1);
$ob2 = new A(2);

$cl = $ob1->getClosure();
echo $cl(); // 1
$cl = $cl->bindTo($ob2);
echo $cl(); // 2
```

It is not possible to bind a function/closure to *arbitrary* objects; at most you can bind it to other instances of the same class it referred to anyway. It's also possible to do this via [`ReflectionMethod::invoke`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php). But again, it's really really not the way PHP (and most traditional OOP languages) works and you should never write code in this way for purposes other than curiosity.

---

`this` and `$this` are *just another variable*. The only thing they do is to *implicitly* carry state without you needing to pass them into all functions you call. In PHP it further contributes to encapsulation, since `$this` can have values which are not accessible from outside the class; that's not even the case with Javascript. As such, there's no real *need* to program this way. Anything you can express with (a theoretical) `$foo->bar->apply($baz)`, you can just as well write as `$foo->bar($baz)` or `bar($baz)`.